# HTML datalist for input text with option value

Tags: html, safari, html-datalist

When in Google Chrome, this allows me to pick "red" and "blue" from a drop down after typing "b" or "r":

```
<input type="text" list="colors" />
<datalist id="colors">
  <option value="red">
  <option  value="blue">
</datalist>
```

However, in Safari it does not.

1. Why?
2. If I wanted it to do so in Safari, what would I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

The `<datalist>` tag is actually not **natively** supported in Safari yet. However, there are a few solutions to the problem. Below is a list of browser compatability with the `<datalist>` tag. 
Chrome: 20.0
IE: 10.0

Firefox: 4.0

Safari: **Not Supported**

Opera: 9.0

*Solution A*

You might consider using a `<select>` tag, though this does have its disadvantages. Unlike the `<datalist>` tag, the user is required to select one of the options you've given. For a `<datalist>` tag, the user can enter anything he wants. 

*Solution B*

Create a `<select>` element and an `<input>` element to match the dual functionality of the `<datalist>` tag.

```
<p>Choose from this list
<select>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
or type in a custom input
<input type="text" name="custominput">
```

*Solution C*

Use a polyfill solution to solve it. This is more complicated. You'll have to use the `modenizr` library to accomplish this task.
http://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/
*Solution D*

You can use a datafill library such as **webshim**, which enables you to reliably use HTML5 features across browsers, despite the lack of native support.
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/

Answer (score 1):

The `datalist` tag is not supported by **Safari** and is partially support by **IE**, checkout the support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist).

You should consider use the [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) tag (with the multiple attribute if you want to allow multiple values):

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

Or you can use [Relevant Dropdown](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/Relevant-Dropdowns) a HTML5 datalist polyfill which could help you to fix your crossbrowser issues.